# I'm looking for half modal that I can operate the back page

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for **half modal that I can operate the back page**.
(It's like when I tap a pin on Google Maps.)

I used showModalBottomSheet, but I can't operate the back page.
I searched for an option that would meet my request, but it didn't exist.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I self-solved.

I use **showBottomSheet**, not showModalBottomSheet.